# What is the best method for making Selenium WebDriver wait for potentially hours at a time?

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I want to write a script using Selenium WebDriver so that I can run it and leave it for a few hours, with the program checking every so often to see if the element I asked for it to search for has appeared.

I'd be using WebDriverWait in order to wait for the element to appear and be clickable.

```
WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((lambda, "tag_to_be_chosen")))
```

I've looked around but haven't found a solid answer yet, but the issue is that after a certain amount of time selenium throws a TimeoutException, because the element still hadn't appeared yet after the page had been loaded (which was expected).

Is there a way to extend the amount of time that the WebDriver will wait for an element to appear indefinitely, so as long as the window is open, the driver is waiting and as soon as the javascript runs, the element is detected and clicked? or I guess alternatively, what would be the cost of increasing the waiting time? obviously if i need it to wait for possibly hours a time, changing seconds from 10 to for example, 3600 seconds.

The docs talk about explicit and implicit wait, but most people only use these for seconds or minutes; not potentially hours.

Comment: If you need to wait hours why not to set timeout to required amount of time? What's wrong with `WebDriverWait(browser, 10000)`?

Comment: Was more asking if there is any cost/downside to doing this

Comment: I don't think so, but I guess it'd be better to increase the interval between calls to, for instance, 1 minute - `WebDriverWait(browser, 10000, 60)`. This should allow you to check `condition` once per minute. Note that default poll frequency is `0.5` seconds and it seem to be very frequent for your case